# LaTex: Get figure caption to align with image

Tags: latex

Thanks in advance for your help!

I know similar questions have been asked, but I cant get any of them to work. I am trying to get the caption to be the same width as the image I am captioning.

Here is the code: it results in all of the words falling in line after the Figure title (image attached to show what it currently looks like.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4E0m.png)

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext} % Package to generate dummy text throughout this template 

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\linespread{1.05} % Line spacing - Palatino needs more space between lines
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage[english]{babel} % Language hyphenation and typographical rules

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} % Custom captions under/above floats in tables or figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{lettrine} % The lettrine is the first enlarged letter at the beginning of the text

\usepackage{enumitem} % Customized lists
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep} % Make itemize lists more compact

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape} % Set the abstract itself to small italic text

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\roman{subsection}} % roman numerals for subsections
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
\fancyhead[C]{Test} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Custom footer text

\usepackage{titling} % Customizing the title section

\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\setlength{\droptitle}{-4\baselineskip} % Move the title up

\pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries} % Article title formatting
\posttitle{\end{center}} 

\setlength\parindent{24pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newsavebox\mysavebox

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{img1.jpg}
\centering
  \caption{Imaged tunnel slide of yeast. This image depicts how yeast cells were counted to determine sample concentrations. Small budding cells were not included in the total cell count. Note: 4× relay lens and 40× objective used. A ${1.75x10^6}$ mL volume is shown.}
    \label{fig:mesh1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you've also been ask for your previous question, please make a [mre] which you add directly to your question. No links to other sites.

Comment: Hello, sorry about that!... I didn't read carefully and thought the code to be minimal (but didn't realize it has to be stand-alone).  It is now updated with all the document setup code included. Hopefully, this is in accordance with community guidelines. If not, I'm all ears. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

- Very important: never ignore error messages. If an error tells you that you mustn't use `floatrow` with the `float` package, don't ignore this error and remove one of the packages.
- Then if you don't want the caption to have an hanging indent, remove the `hang` option from the `caption` package.
- don't abuse the letter `x` as multiplication symbol. Use `\times` instead.
- have a look at the `siunitx` package to get correct spacing and fonts for units
- with `7.5cm` your image is too wide for your column, a warning in the log file will tell you this. You can avoid this by using `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext} % Package to generate dummy text throughout this template 

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\linespread{1.05} % Line spacing - Palatino needs more space between lines
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage[english]{babel} % Language hyphenation and typographical rules

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage[small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} % Custom captions under/above floats in tables or figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{lettrine} % The lettrine is the first enlarged letter at the beginning of the text

\usepackage{enumitem} % Customized lists
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep} % Make itemize lists more compact

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape} % Set the abstract itself to small italic text

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\roman{subsection}} % roman numerals for subsections
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
\fancyhead[C]{Test} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Custom footer text

\usepackage{titling} % Customizing the title section

\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\setlength{\droptitle}{-4\baselineskip} % Move the title up

\pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries} % Article title formatting
\posttitle{\end{center}} 

\setlength\parindent{24pt}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newsavebox\mysavebox

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\centering
  \caption{Imaged tunnel slide of yeast. This image depicts how yeast cells were counted to determine sample concentrations. Small budding cells were not included in the total cell count. Note: 4× relay lens and 40× objective used. A ${1.75 \times 10^6}$ mL volume is shown.}
    \label{fig:mesh1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sam, thank you so much for your help!                  1)  I didn't actually receive an error message for those two float packages, but the entire first block of code that I included was red, not sure why. 
2) I made changes to the caption package; it worked great, thanks!
3) I actually tried \linewidth before but the image ended up being too wide so I customized the width so it looked best. Again, not sure why so I will have to continue to mess with it. 

Again, thank you so much for your help and sorry to start off with such unhelpful code.

Comment: @cw5320 I bet there was an error message, but overleaf is very good at hiding them behind a tiny red square at the top right

Comment: Okay sweet, I will keep that in mind. You have saved me so much time thanks! Can't wait until I can give back to the Community.

Comment: @cw5320 You're welcome!